# bash execute variable (with command that held variable which is created inside if statement )

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, command, local-variables

Hi i have script as below:

```
mode= loop1 or loop2
command1="screen -dm -S $name feh *.jpg"

if [ "$(screen -S loop1 -X select . ; echo $?)" != 0 ] && [[ $mode != "loop1" ]];then 
name="loop1"
eval "$command1"
elif [ "$(screen -S loop2 -X select . ; echo $?)" != 0 ] && [[ $mode != "loop2" ]] ;then
name="loop2"
eval "$command1"
else 
echo "error"
fi
```

Basically it check if there is screen session named loop1 or loop2 if there is not, it evaluate variable $command1 which inside have another variable $name which should have change when the bash get inside loop. the problem is that variable $command1 is initialized globally before if statement start and in that time there is no variable $date.

When loop evaluate $command1 it do not use variable $name setted line before in loop statement.

I need pass to the variable command1 value of variable name

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment, this is a FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

A sensible workaround is to refactor the command into a parametrized function. The conditionals should also be cleared up of pretzel logic -- printing a command's exit code and comparing it to the string zero is a clumsy way to reimplement the basic functionality of the built-in `if` conditional!

```
mode=loop1 # or loop2
run_feh (} {
    screen -dm -S "$1" feh *.jpg
}

no_screen_of_loop () {
    ! screen -S "$1" -X select . && [[ "$2" != "$1" ]]
}

if no_screen_of_loop "loop1" "$mode"; then
    run_feh "loop1"
elif no_screen_of_loop "loop2" "$mode"; then
    run_feh "loop2"
else 
    echo "error" >&2    # note stderr
fi
```

If having a value in `$name` after the conditional is necessary, a slight additional refactoring will be necessary.

Comment: i like your solution is more proffesional but i have question the "screen -S loop1 -X select ." return 0 if will find the screen session with gived name but return "No screen session found" when doesnt. So this is the resaon why i used "[ "$(screen -S loop1 -X select . ; echo $?)" != 0 ]"  this is right?  because in your modification does the "if" conditional return error if it will no be 0 or 1 ?

Comment: If you want to suppress the error message, use `screen 2>/dev/null`

Comment: The purpose of `if` is to run a command and examine its exit code. It is not an error for a command to fail, with any non-zero exit code; it is the quite regular way to select the `else` branch. If the command's exit code is zero, the `then` branch is taken.

Comment: i checked all possibility's and yours was the most flexible so your answear resolve my problem

Comment: can i use function parameter as binary operator in conditional, example     no_screen_of_loop ()  [[ $abc "$1" "abc"  ]]
}

Comment: That seems crazy but there is no syntactic reason you can't. Though think of the poor sod who needs to understand your program (probably yourself, a few months hence).

Answer (score 1):

While chepner is **entirely** correct that you are going to run into [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) problems and you shouldn't try to do that.

The more immediate problem here is an evaluation order issue.

When the shell runs this line `command1="screen -dm -S $name feh *.jpg"` it is expanding `$name` at that point (which, as you'll notice, is **before** you've assigned the name variable a value).

Switching the order of those (groups of) lines would work for this issue but wouldn't do anything for the *other* [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) issues.

Additionally, `[ "$(screen -S loop1 -X select . ; echo $?)" != 0 ]` is an inefficient and unnecessary way to test a command for a successful return code.

`[` is a command (also known as `test`). It **isn't** an integral part of the syntax of an `if` statement.

The syntax of an `if` statement in the shell is `if <command>; then ... fi` where `<command>` can be anything that returns a return code appropriately. `[` just happens to be a commonly used command in that space.

But if your command (`screen -S loop1 -X select .` in this case) *already* returns success/failure appropriately then you can avoid `[` entirely and just use your command.

```
if ! screen -S loop1 -X select . && [[ $mode != "loop1" ]];then 
    name="loop1"
elif ! screen -S loop2 -X select . && [[ $mode != "loop2" ]] ;then
    name="loop2"
else 
    echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: My understanding of the conditionals is that they should succeed if `screen` *fails.* So you'd need a `!` to negate its exit code. In my answer, I went into the additional effort to encapsulate this, too, into a function.

Comment: @tripleee Right, thanks for catching my logic inversion. Yeah, if your answer had been there when I started writing mine I probably wouldn't have written it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
mode= loop1 or loop2
command1="screen -dm -S name feh *.jpg"

if [ "$(screen -S loop1 -X select . ; echo $?)" != 0 ] && [[ $mode !=     "loop1" ]];then 
eval "${command1/name/loop1}"
elif [ "$(screen -S loop2 -X select . ; echo $?)" != 0 ] && [[ $mode !=     "loop2" ]] ;then
eval "${command1/name/loop2}"
else 
echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: This isn't a "solution" it is a hack on top of a bad idea.